# Problem with making the hero section of this site responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid, bootstrap-5

I'm experiencing problems on why the hero section which I'm building isn't responsive, I'm using bootstrap and the grid system,  the image I the hero section is responsive as I'm using the class img-fluid but the text and buttons don't follow suit I'm really confused to where I've gone wrong and help would be massively appreciated as I've been banging my head against a wall for an hour on end now.

**here's the HTML:**

```
<!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header id="header" class="fixed-top">
    <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">

      <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/logo.png"></a>
      <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
      <!-- <a href="index.html" class="logo mr-auto"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt=""></a>-->

      <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
          <li class="drop-down"><a href="">Drop Down</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 1</a></li>
              <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Deep Drop Down</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 5</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->

    </div>
  </header><!-- End Header -->

  <!-- ======= Hero Section ======= -->
  <section id="hero" class="d-flex align-items-center">

    <div class="container" data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-delay="100">
    <div class="hero-image">
    <img src="assets/img/hero-img.png" class="img-fluid">
    </div>

    <div class="hero-textbox">
      <h2 class="hero-heading-text">WINNING WITH DATA:<br> 
CRM AND ANALYTICS FOR THE BUSINESS OF <br>SPORTS</h2>
<p class="hero-description-text">Suitable for beginners, intermediaries or digital marketers who haven't yet included data-driven decision making in their approach. Our book provides a fantastic start for those looking to understand the role of CRM and Business Intelligence for the sports industry.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Order Now</a>
    
    </div>
  </div>
  </section><!-- End Hero -->
```

**here's the CSS:**
https://pastebin.com/F3ghpywz

Thank you so much in advance for helping me solve this problem.

Kind regards,
Josh.

Comment: Can you paste only the relevant, minimal code needed to solve your porobem, so that I can solve your issue more easily.

Comment: @koder613 I have updated the  question  with only the code  for the  header/hero section  

-Thanks in Advance